# I have column x in hh:mm format of datatype varchar in SQL Server and I want to perform sum on that 'x' column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column `x` in `hh:mm` format of datatype `varchar` in SQL Server and I want to perform sum on that `x` column.

I created a user-defined function to convert total min into `hh:mm` format.

Then I tried to perform `sum` to calculate total duration:

```
sum(cast(new_totalmin AS Int))
```

4. also i want total of HH:mm exactly as example
   4:20
   +1:10

---

5:30
5 hour: 30 minute

5. or i can do one thing here insted hh:mm i keep column as it is which is totalmin  as int once sum cal insted of hh:mm (hh.mm which is  in decimal also ok for me   PSB it will be ok for me ':' or '.' format )
   (60 min --> 1:00   --> 1.00

   ```
         90 min -->  1:30   -->1.30
        ---------------------------------
   ```

   sum -->        150 min -->2:30 --> 2.30)

but it did not work.

I got an error like

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '01:00' to data type int

Comment: Well - pretty simple: a value like `12:45` is just simply **NOT** an `INT` - so don't try to convert it to an `INT` ......

Comment: Either you have to sum the total minutes of hh:mm, or you should review what you really want.

Comment: You really need to fix your design; don't store times as a `varchar`. There is a `time` data type for a reason, and you can use numerical data types for durations. Both are vastly better than a `varchar` for such data.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE (HourMinutes VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES ('4:32');
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES ('5:28');
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES ('6:00');
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES ('7:10');

SELECT * FROM @SampleData

SELECT SUM(datediff(minute, 0, HourMinutes)) TotalMinute 
FROM @SampleData
```

You will get following output

[image]

Comment: your answer is correct also work for me but the sum is not right

Comment: why the sum is not right? Please explain.

Comment: 4:32+5:28+6:00+7:10 =23:10 it should near about 23hour and 10 min

Comment: You are right, it should be 23 Hour 10 Minute = 1380 + 10 Minute = 1390 Minute. So the result of the query match your expectation. Sum is absolutely correct. When you have a correct sum in minutes I believe you can represent it to any format like 23:10 or so.

Answer (score 0):

`hh:mm` is a varchar data and applying SUM will not work on it.

As you are telling that you are already having a function, I would suggest you to perform sum of the minutes and then later convert them to `hh:mm`

```
SELECT ... , YourUserDefinedFunction(sum(minuteData)) as minutesInHHMM_Format
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
```

Comment: thanks for your  time guys really appreciate this issue solved for me now .

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you store numeric values -- such as the number of minutes -- as a number rather than a string.

The challenge is converting the value back to an HH:MM format.  SQL Server does not support time values of 24 hours or greater, so you need to use string manipulations.

Assuming that your values are all less than 24 hours, you can use:

```
select sum(datediff(minute, 0, hhmm)) as num_minutes,
       concat(sum(datediff(minute, 0, hhmm)) / 60, ':',
              format(sum(datediff(minute, 0, hhmm)) % 60, '00')
             )
from t;
```

The result here is a string, so this can exceed 24 hours.

A more general solution eschews date/times altogether:

```
select sum(v.minutes) as num_minutes,
       concat(sum(v.minutes) / 60, ':',
              format(sum(v.minutes) % 60, '00')
             )
from t cross apply
     (values (left(t.hhmm, charindex(':', t.hhmm) - 1) * 60 + right(t.hhmm, 2))
     ) v(minutes);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f2a32f8923bbad577555f08b18399cd8) is a db<>fiddle.